# Unknown Edge in Ipad after applying Subsurf Modifier

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

I am trying to make an Ipad in blender 2.82 but it having some folds on the top left hand corner. See the picture below

[image]

I don't know why it is happening. Pls help me!!!

This is solid view mode

[image]

This edit mode

[image]

And this is x ray mode in edit mode

[image]

This is the blender file-  [image]

Comment: hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I have added the file.

Comment: Pls check it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few interiror faces in the frame of the device (marked on the first picture) which cause this problem. You used the same face for the backplate of the ipad and for the screen what is never recommended, create two independent face for them.
[image]

After you fixed the geometry you have to add mean crease to the sharp edges (marked on the second picture).

[image]

After you apply the modifier the best if you dissolve the middle edges to avoid the unnecessary bending (third picture).

[image]

https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/odmEMaaY

Comment: Thanks a lot i will try to do it. 